# Translating props in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I am using vuex-i18n to translate my strings and bootstrap-vue for styling.
Every bootstrap-component has props that I need to translate:

```
<b-input id="input2" placeholder="Username" />
```

Vue binds the raw text (here: Username) to the placeholder-prop and it obviously gets rendered verbatim (Username).

If I want to translate my placeholder, I think I have to bind it to a variable or computed property

```
<b-input id="input2" :placeholder="username" />
```

and translate it in the script section:

```
computed: {
  username() {
    return this.$t('forms.placeholders.username')
  }
```

That is getting very verbose. Is there a better way?

Clarification:
What I would like to avoid, is having to create dozens of computed properties which basically return a translated string of the property's name:

```
placeholder=*username*
...
*username* ()
  return $t('*username*')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can directly pass the localized string into the prop instead of handling it inside the target component:

`<b-input id="input2" :placeholder="$t('forms.placeholders.' + username)" />`

You can also create a helper function by creating a vue [plugin](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html) to wrap this code and make it shorter:

```
Vue.use({
    install(Vue) {
        Vue.prototype.localizedTextFct = function (placeholder) {
            return this.$t('forms.placeholders.' + placeholder)
        }
    }
});

new Vue({
    ...
})
```

and you can now use the helper function like this:

`<b-input id="input2" :placeholder="localizedTextFct(username)" />`

Comment: What exactly would that accomplish? I tried it and it rendered to `forms.placehpolders.$(this.placeholder}` - as you would expect

Comment: it is string interpolation.  It is `${this.placeholder}` and not `$(this.placeholder}`. You are using open parenthesis. It should be curly bracket

Comment: My fault. In my code I have curly brackets - the problem was the backtick. Still: like this I also have to have a $placeholder variable - where do I get that from ?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are trying to achieve. Is what you wanted is to eliminate the adding of a computed property for referencing the localized string inside the component where the placeholder is passed?

Comment: Im trying to prevent the code getting bloated with dozens of computed statements like the `localizedPlaceholder`one, that basically return, what in non i18n apps is set directly in the prop

Comment: You don't necessarily need to create a computed property for each but instead pass directly the localized version from the prop: `<b-input id="input2" :placeholder="$t('forms.placeholders.' + username)" />`

Comment: Thats much better - thank you. If I now could just use my own function instead of $t -  `:placeholder = "localizedTextFct('placeholder1')"`

Comment: Yes you can, by creating a vue plugin.

Comment: I've updated my answer containing a code showing how to create a helper function that you can directly use in your template.

Comment: You can find the documentation for creating vue plugin in here: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html

Answer (score 0):

You can translate props in vue and nuxt through computed property.
See below code.

```
computed: {
  userName() {
    return this.$t('forms.username')
}
```